# What exactly is google web search index?

Tags: search-engine

I have read many descriptions which vaguely touch google search index. Eg: "Google essentially gathers the pages during the crawl process and then creates an index, so we know exactly how to look things up."

My question is:
1. What is an index ? Is it a key value map ?

2. If yes, then what is they key and what is the value ? Is key the search word we googled up?
3. What is value of the map ? Is it simply the URL or is it storing actual HTML pages ?
4. What database is being used ? MySQL ? Some sort of NoSQL ?

Comment: #BayesianMachineLearning - There is an insane amount of complexity into how google serves up its search engine.

Comment: I think you can start about reading information retrieval and specially inverted indexing, to get you kick started.

Answer (score 0):

This should help your research.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank

just one of many tools in their toolbox. 
The statement from google and the questions are too broad to really mean anything.